# Java - using Scanner to pull Strings and Ints from a file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make an array for ParkingArea(string, int, int, int, int). The file that is getting scanned is here http://uwf.edu/jcoffey/data.txt

```
try
{
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
  for (int i = 0;scan.hasNext(); i++)
  {
    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
      if(x == 0)
      {
        name = scan.next();
      }
      else
      {
        array[x-1] = scan.next();
      }
    }
    ParkingArea[i] = new ParkingArea(name, array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
  }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this error when I compile.

```
Parking.java:40: error: incompatible types
              array[x-1] = scan.next();
                                    ^
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define `array` (ie. what type of object is it)?

Comment: Most likely, you need to use `scan.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scan.next() returns a String. If you want to convert it to an int, you need to call `

```
Integer.parseInt(scan.next())
```

Comment: Its more efficient to use the Scanner to do the conversion work, by calling `scanner.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
array[x-1] = scan.next();
```

give

```
array[x-1] = scan.nextInt();
```

a try. Assuming that `array` is of type `int[]`, then your issue comes from assigning the `int` value at `array[x-1]` to a `String`, which is what `scan.next()` returns. Using `scan.nextInt()` will return an `int`, thus solving the error.